# Laravel - How to pluck a nested collection?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, collections

Ok, so i'm building a table that records time entries for each month of the year. I have a variable called $group_months, if I dump the data I get this:

```
Collection {#189 ▼
  #items: array:4 [▼
    "Comp Time Used" => Collection {#294 ▼
      #items: array:3 [▼
        10 => "12:00:00"
        11 => "09:00:00"
        "01" => "12:00:00"
      ]
    }
    "Vacation Time Used" => Collection {#324 ▼
      #items: array:1 [▼
        11 => "04:00:00"
      ]
    }
    "Sick Time" => Collection {#327 ▼
      #items: array:1 [▼
        10 => "03:15:00"
      ]
    }
    "OT Accrued" => Collection {#318 ▼
      #items: array:1 [▼
        10 => "12:00:00"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I'de like to be able to pluck out heading of each collection and use them as columns for my table. So I want to pluck out "Comp Time Used" to use it as a column in my table. Then I'de want to pluck out "12:00:00' and use it for my October row in my table. (10 = October)

TableView:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-sm">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Month</th>
                    <th scope="col">Overtime Hours</th>
                    <th scope="col">Compensation Hours</th>
                    <th scope="col">Vacation</th>
                    <th scope="col">Personal Hours</th>
                    <th scope="col">Sick Hours</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="row">Jan</th>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="row">Feb</th>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="row">Mar</th>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="row">Apr</th>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="row">May</th>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="row">Jun</th>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="row">Jul</th>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="row">Aug</th>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <th scope="row">Sep</th>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">Oct</th>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">Nov</th>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">Dec</th>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
     </table>
```

Times Migration:

```
 Schema::create('times', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->date('start_day');
            $table->text('category');
            $table->time('start_time');
            $table->time('finish_time');
            $table->time('duration');
            $table->text('notes');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');

        });
```

TableController:

```
 public function show(User $user) 
    {

        $data = $user->times()->whereYear('start_day', 2019)->get();
        $group_months = $data->groupBy(function($entry) {
            return $entry->category;
        })->map(function($items) {
            return $items->groupBy(function($entry) {
                return Carbon::parse($entry->start_day)->format('m');
            })
        ->map(function($items) {
            $duration = $items->first()->duration;
            return $duration;
            });
        });

 return view('table.show', compact('data','group_months'));
```

Comment: Can you give an example with a little more data, both input and desired output?

Comment: I edited my original post

Comment: So you basically want to change the hierarchy between the months and column names, e.g. `['10' => ['Comp Time Used' => '12:00:00', 'Sick Time' => '03:15:00'], 11 => ['Comp Time Used' => '09:00:00', 'Vacation Time Used' => '04:00:00']]`? Do you need each column name for each month and if so, what is the default value in case no value is available (e.g. `null`)?

Comment: Yea exactly. I'll update my post with my table to show you the format. If theirs no data entries for lets say Sick time then the collection won't show an array for sick time. It'll just show the 3 other values (OT,personal,vacation)

Comment: I updated my post with more information pertaining to what i'm trying to do

Comment: That can be done much simpler. I'll provide an answer after dinner.

Comment: Ok thanks alot. I appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently querying all your data, grouping it in-memory which isn't really quite efficient. Instead, you should push as much as possible to the database. This also means querying only the relevant data: `category`, `month` and `sum(duration)`

```
public function show(User $user) 
{
    $data = $user->times()
        ->whereYear('start_day', 2019)
        ->groupBy('category', \DB::raw('month(start_date)'))
        ->select([
            'category',
            \DB::raw('month(start_date) as month'),
            \DB::raw('sum(duration) as duration'),
        ])
        ->orderBy(\DB::raw('month(start_date)'))
        ->get()
        ->mapToGroups(function ($item) {
            $month = \DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $item['month'])->format('M');
            return [$month => [$item['category'] => $this->formatDuration($item['duration'])]];
        })
        ->mapWithKeys(function ($item, $key) {
            return [$key => $item->collapse()];
        });

    return view('table.show', compact('data'));
}

private function formatDuration($seconds)
{
    $duration = '';

    if ($seconds < 0) {
        $duration = '-';
        $seconds  = abs($seconds);
    }

    $hours    = floor($seconds / 3600);
    $seconds -= $hours * 3600;
    $minutes  = floor($seconds / 60);
    $seconds -= $minutes * 60;

    return $duration . sprintf('%d:%02d:%02d', $hours, $minutes, $seconds);
}
```

At this point, `$data` contains something of the following structure:

```
[
    'Jan' => [
        'Category 1' => '1:20:40',
        'Category 2' => '15:05:40',
        'Category 4' => '0:00:50'
    ],
    'Feb' => [
        'Category 2' => '2:30:15',
        'Category 3' => '4:45:30'
    ]
]
```

We can use this data to generate our table in a generic way, using the array index as month number.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-sm">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Month</th>
            <th scope="col">Overtime Hours</th>
            <th scope="col">Compensation Hours</th>
            <th scope="col">Vacation</th>
            <th scope="col">Personal Hours</th>
            <th scope="col">Sick Hours</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($data as $month => $row)
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">{{ $month }}</th>
                <td>{{ $row['Overtime Hours'] ?? '-' }}</td>
                <td>{{ $row['Compensation Hours'] ?? '-' }}</td>
                <td>{{ $row['Vacation'] ?? '-' }}</td>
                <td>{{ $row['Personal Hours'] ?? '-' }}</td>
                <td>{{ $row['Sick Hours'] ?? '-' }}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

---

If you want each month to be shown in the table, even if there is no data available for the month, you can add the missing indexes to the collection using `array_fill(1, 12, [])` as base:

```
public function show(User $user) 
{
    $data = collect(array_fill(1, 12, []))
        ->replace(
            $user->times()
                ->whereYear('start_day', 2019)
                ->groupBy('category', \DB::raw('month(start_date)'))
                ->select([
                    'category',
                    \DB::raw('month(start_date) as month'),
                    \DB::raw('sum(duration) as duration'),
                ])
                ->orderBy(\DB::raw('month(start_date)'))
                ->get()
                ->mapToGroups(function ($item) {
                    return [$item['month'] => [
                        $item['category'] => $this->formatDuration($item['duration'])
                    ]];
                })
                ->mapWithKeys(function ($item, $key) {
                    return [$key => $item->collapse()];
                })
        )
        ->mapToGroups(function ($item, $key) {
            $month = \DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $key)->format('M');
            return [$month => $item];
        });

    return view('table.show', compact('data'));
}
```

Comment: Wow, amazing. Thanks for your time to put in such a detailed and clean code response. The table is working except for the fact each row is displaying '-' instead of the times recorded, any idea why? Also is there a way to show every month in the table even if there's no recorded values, because right now it's just showing the months that have time entries.

Comment: @stormakt You'd need to swap the row columns with the exact categories from your table, e.g. `$row['Vacation Time Used']` as mentioned in your question. I didn't know all of them, so I simply used the column headers of the table as index. -- I added an extended version with filled months to the answer. It's gettin' complex though. :)

Comment: I updated my DB by removing the category column from my times table and added a categories table. I'm referencing the ID on the table. I made a new thread because i'm running into an issue with the data not showing. Could you help me out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58646159/laravel-table-not-showing-data