# Laravel - Table not showing data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, html-table, eloquent

I'm building a time tracker and i'm trying to fill up a table with the total time logged for each category type for each month of the year. I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong but my table isn't showing any data. I believe it has to do with the way i'm calling my rows, each number represents the category_id, ex:

```
<td>{{ $row[1] ?? '-' }}</td>
```

This is supposed to be using the total time from category_id 1 which is Overtime Hours.

Here's more info to make things more clear.

Controller:

```
 public function show(User $user) 
    {
        $data = collect(array_fill(1, 12, []))
            ->replace(
                $user->times()
                    ->whereYear('start_day', 2019)
                    ->groupBy('category_id', \DB::raw('month(start_day)'))
                    ->select([
                        'category_id',
                        \DB::raw('month(start_day) as month'),
                        \DB::raw('sum(duration) as duration'),
                    ])
                    ->orderBy(\DB::raw('month(start_day)'))
                    ->get()
                    ->mapToGroups(function ($item) {
                        return [$item['month'] => [
                            $item['category_id'] => $this->formatDuration($item['duration'])
                        ]];
                    })
                    ->mapWithKeys(function ($item, $key) {
                        return [$key => $item->collapse()];
                    })
            )
            ->mapToGroups(function ($item, $key) {
                $month = \DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $key)->format('M');
                return [$month => $item];
            });

        return view('report.show', compact('data'));
    }
```

If I dd($data), here's an example of 1 month.

```
 "Oct" => Collection {#330 ▼
      #items: array:1 [▼
        0 => Collection {#333 ▼
          #items: array:1 [▼
            0 => "33:20:00" 
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

**This line should be showing 1 => "33:20:00"  not 0=> "33:20:00", because it belongs to category_id = 1. So there must be a problem with my queries.**

Table:

```
  <table class="table table-striped table-sm">
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th scope="col">Month</th>
              <th scope="col">Overtime Hours</th>
              <th scope="col">Compensation Hours</th>
              <th scope="col">Vacation</th>
              <th scope="col">Personal Hours</th>
              <th scope="col">Sick Hours</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          @foreach($data as $month => $row)
              <tr>
                  <th scope="row">{{ $month }}</th>
                  <td>{{ $row[1] ?? '-' }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $row[2] ?? '-' }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $row[3] ?? '-' }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $row[4] ?? '-' }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $row[5] ?? '-' }}</td>
              </tr>
          @endforeach
      </tbody>
  </table>
```

Migration for the form data:

```
   public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('times', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->date('start_day');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');
            $table->time('start_time');
            $table->time('finish_time');
            $table->time('duration');
            $table->text('notes');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');

        });
    }
```

Migration for categories:

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('type');
        });
    }
```

Home Controller:

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        DB::table('categories')->insertOrIgnore([
            ['type' => 'OT Accrued'],
            ['type' => 'Comp Time Used'],
            ['type' => 'Vacation Time Used'],
            ['type' => 'Personal Hours Used'],
            ['type' => 'Sick Time']
      ]);
    }
```

Comment: I'm actually pretty confident that this isn't the queries fault. Have you checked your table and verified that the `category_id` column does not contain a `0` anywhere (normally a `0` is not assigned as auto-incrementing identifier by the DB, so this must be true).

Comment: @Namoshek. Doesn't contain a 0. Here's an image of the table from phpmyadmin.  https://imgur.com/a/Eu9CX73

I'm inserting those categories through my Homepage Controller so they're always there even if I run a php artisan migrate:fresh. I added the home controller to my op

Comment: That are the categories themselves, but what about the referencing `category_id` column?

Comment: @Namoshek. Nope, no zeros. Here's a screenshot of the times table. https://imgur.com/a/4Qh51Jz - I added one time entry for each category as you can see.

And here's the dd of the data: https://imgur.com/a/0DkNkDY

Comment: @Namoshek any ideas?

Comment: Not really. You could try forcing the key to be a string, maybe that stops resetting the array: `$item['category_id'] => $this->formatDuration($item['duration'])` -> `strval($item['category_id']) => $this->formatDuration($item['duration'])`

Comment: @Namoshek Nope, doesn't change anything.. Hmm maybe I should go back to the structure I had it before with category as a column. Thanks for the help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201691/discussion-between-stormakt-and-namoshek).